# Can I use a small BBQ regulator to reduce propane line pressure from 10 PSI to 11" wc?

Tags: propane

Propane company hooked up my permanent propane line today to the garage. I told them to put a T with shutoff BEHIND the 2nd stage regulator, (for a future propane generator). But they put the T in the line that comes from the high pressure regulator! (see below schematic).

So, as I understand, the T and valve output now have 10 PSI ? 
I looked on the generator specs and it requires household pressure, 11" wc.

Can I use a small bbq regulator to reduce from 10 PSI to 11" wc, I found one that meets the BTU requirements of the genny.

```
1000 gal propane tank
|
at the tank, red high pressure regulator
|
|---at the garage, a T that goes to 1/4 turn shutoff valve---> to generator
|
at the garage, green 2nd stage regulator
|
garage heater
```

Answer (score 1):

No. You can not put the bbq unit 'approved for occasional supervised use' on a 1000 pound propane tank.

We can, however talk about the maximum blood alcohol level of an adult, before he/she is no longer considered capable of 'supervising' a bbq.

---

dan - the bottle cable just is not designed for what you want to do. I can dig up UL listing information for you. But this is not about 'code', this is honestly concern about you, and your safety.

There are a few things in life that are just not worth saving a bit of money. Health care, electricity and combustible gasses are at the top of that list. There are some things, generic drugs, copper plated electrical load centers, and world series tickets that are not on the 50 yard line, some things are ok.

Doing gas lines on the cheap, please don't.

I can argue for and against what you suggest. I can not stop you from using the bottle tank hose.

You came here looking for advice, mine is don't do this.

Comment: the bbq regulator would not go on the 1000 gal. tank. It would go after the high pressure regulator on the tank, so inlet pressure into the bbq reg. would be 10 psi.